# Listing clubs and businesses

Tags: intellectual-property

If I created an android/IOS app that listed the names of businesses/clubs (leisure such as golf, etc.) would I need the consent of each club/business or would I be able to list their addresses without any legal repercussions?

I am based in the UK but I guess international law would apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be fine: the name of the club and its address are facts - there is no intellectual property in facts.

It would be even better if you adopted a procedure allowing the clubs to request their removal from the list if they want. Not a legal requirement but good customer service.